# How to disable /* autocomplete in Visual Studio 2012 (or Resharper)

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-7.0

I have Visual Studio 2012 with Resharper installed. When editing css files, when I type `/*`, I get autocompletion like so: `/**/`

I would like to **disable that**, but I cannot find it in the options menu.

Where can I disable that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One way to avoid this annoyance is to add the closing comment symbols first.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools -> options -> text editor -> all languages(or chose one), and untick `Automatic brace completion`. You can also search for it in options menu.