# Disable visual studio autocomplete comment in javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, comments

My problem is simple. Whenever I type "/*" in javascript or typescript file in VisualStudio, editor adds "*/" so I get: "/* */". I like to disable this autocomplete feature because its annoying. I want to just type "/*" and have only this.

Where I can disable this autocomplete function? I was looking in resharper and visualstudio options and I couldnt find anything about it.

Comment: Try: Tools -> Options... -> TextEditor -> C# -> IntelliSense

Comment: Use a different Text Editor. I would recommend Sublime Text 2, it allows you to change settings for pretty much *everything*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable /\* autocomplete in Visual Studio 2012 (or Resharper)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936215/how-to-disable-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-2012-or-resharper)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for C++, too. 
Try to disable "Menu | Tools | Options |  | General | Automatic brace completion" - this worked for me. I couldn't reproduce your problem with a JavaScript 'Script1.js' file. For JavaScript I always got only "/*". Nevertheless it might help.

Comment: Menu | Tools | Options, and then Text Editor. Worked for me in VS 2017.

Answer (score -2):

Its JavaScript IntelliSense 'feature'.  It will be easier to get used to it than to turn it off.  Turning it off will turn off other features that you will find usefull