# Disable Autocomplete of block comments in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I begin a block comment, `/*`, VS automatically follows up by inserting the corresopnding `*/` right after it.  This is inconvenient for me, because my primary use case of block comments is to temporarily disable blocks of code, meaning I want to insert the `*/` manually.

Is there a way to turn off the autocomplete specifically, and only, for comments?

Comment: Select the code and use `Ctrl+K,C` to comment a block of code, `Ctrl+K,U` to uncomment it

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742412/disable-visual-studio-autocomplete-comment-in-javascript

Comment: While that is useful, I'm wondering if there is a way to turn off the (very annoying) autocomplete for when I want to do it manually.

Comment: I definitely do NOT want to turn off Intellisense.

Comment: @MartinBonner, it is sort of a duplicate.  I'm on Visual Studio 2015, so things might have changed between versions.  I will update the question tags.

Comment: It *might* have changed - but I fear not :-(

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a setting in the IDE to disable this behavior. You will have to look for 3rd-party extensions. A (commercial) 3rd-party extension to make this more convenient is [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/). It allows you to select a block of code and enter `*` to comment out/in that block of code, using block comments (see [Surround Selection](http://www.wholetomato.com/features/feature-coding-assistance.asp#surround) for details).

Comment: Still another option is to use `#if 0 ... #endif`, which works even with nested `/* comments */`.

Comment: See this [thread , if you use c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307602/how-to-disable-the-automatic-asterisk-in-visual-studio-when-adding-a-multi-line) 'Tools > Options... > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Uncheck "Generate XML Documentation comments for ///". '